# Now that the android command is deprecated how to should i create android apps without android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanted to work without android studio as it really slows my laptop down.So I after research I got to the deprecated android command.As it is deprecated ,Is there another way to create android apps without android studio
I also looked at cookie-cutter and similar apps.They all have one problem-They don't dynamically update the android gradle plugin on updates and are also separated from the android command line tools

Comment: "Is there another way to create android apps without android studio" -- copy an existing project directory and make the desired changes. Build the app using Gradle from the command line (e.g., `./gradlew installDebug`).

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about your project could be useful.
If you're using Gradle, each of your build variants/flavors will have a command for building.
More information can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

and

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips

Comment: My project's a python project that completely replaces android studio , except of course the IDE type features.All the android app related stuff is hopefully going to make it in my app